# Cart autoupdate on insufficient quantity

Tags: prestashop

Hello i have the following issue. I have a customer that have been building his cart over 3 days with over 100 products, however during that time one (or more) of the products have reached 0 quantity and he can't finish the purchase. Is there a way to make it so that when this happens the name of the product to change color or some other indication so the person buying can see wich product is insufficient so that he can remove it ?
I have searched for modules that will be able to do that but i was unable to find any i am using prestashop 1.5.5.0 .

I hope for a fast response and resolution because he is an important client and i don't want to miss him.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check in your template (shopping_cart_line), the "quantity_available" property of your `$product`. If it's 0 or less, change add a css class.